# Is it possible to have HTML in a tooltip in amcharts 5

Tags: amcharts, amcharts5

I would like to add a link to a tooltip in [amcharts5](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/). I see documentation for using tooltipHTML in version 4, but no mention in the docs either way if this is possible in amcharts5.  Using tooltipHTML doesn't seem to work.

Comment: HTML tooltips are currently not supported in v5. [It is under consideration](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts5/issues/35#issuecomment-937459734).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see [their documentation.](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/common-elements/tooltips/#HTML_in_tooltips)

```
series.columns.template.setAll({
  tooltipHTML: "<strong>{categoryX}</strong>: {valueY}"
});
```

[Here's](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/NWYbJeX) an example.